# firebase analytics.logEvent doesn't work in android 5 webview

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, android-webview, firebase-analytics

I'm using FireBase analytics in my website. as their documentation says, I have inserted the following codes at the end of `<body>`:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = firebase.analytics();
```

and then I use `analytics.logEvent(...);` in my javascript code to log events. it works fine in chrome for example, but I just tested my site in android webview on a device with android 5.1 and my `javascript` gets stuck at this line: `analytics.logEvent(...);` and the codes after that doesn't run.

I can see this error in the console:

```
com.android.browser E/browser: Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logEvent' of undefined https://example.com/document.js:366
```

what's the problem?